# fixed header on scroll not working in ie8

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

i have implemented a jquery for fix header when user scrolls down the header will get fix position. But it is working in all browser except ie8. could anyone suggest the correct way.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).scroll(function()
    {
        var window_y = $(window).scrollTop();
        var header_h = $('.header').height();
        if(window_y > header_h)
        {
            $(".header").addClass('fixed');
        }
        else
        {
            $(".header").removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Working reference is [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2THyB/3/)

Comment: suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem

Comment: the fiddle link is updated does it make sense now? or anything more you need i want to make the header part to be as "shopper.queldorei.com" just scroll down the header it will get fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and this will work fine or also you can give fixed height of header without make
variable of header pls try first console

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var header_h = $('.header').height();
    //console.log(header_h);
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > header_h) 
    {
        $(".header").addClass('fixed');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $(".header").removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

let me know if you have any issue when you try this

Comment: no benefit to head height variable unless you move it out of scroll handler, which is good idea since scroll event fires many times a second

Comment: i have a live work of like this and this is working in ie8 fine but now working in ie7 here is the link and you can check this http://msg91.com/india/